# Proving $\operatorname {rank} A + \operatorname {rank} B \le n $

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices such that $AB = 0$. Prove that
>   $\operatorname {rank} A + \operatorname {rank} B \le n $.

What I did is to show that if the multiplication of the two matrices is zero then

$\displaystyle\sum^n_1a_{1,i}b_{i,1}=0\\
\displaystyle\sum^n_1a_{2,i}b_{i,2}=0\\
...\\
\displaystyle\sum^n_1a_{n,i}b_{i,n}=0$

So there has to be at least $n$ zeros in one or two of the matrices in order for $AB = 0$, so there are at least $n$ linearly dependent rows so the rank of the product is at most $n$.

I'm pretty sure this isn't rigorous enough nor on the right track.

Comment: It isn't true that there are at least $n$ zeros. Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. $AB=0$

Comment: How about try contradiction suppose that rank $A$+rank$B$>$n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $AB=0$ we have $im(B)\subseteq Ker(A)$. This implies $rank(B)\leq dim(Ker(A))$. Consequently,
\begin{equation}
n=rank(A)+dim(Ker(A))\geq rank(A)+rank(B).
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you explain this $im(B)\subseteq Ker(A)$ ?

Comment: For every $x\in im(B)$ we have $x=By$ for some $y$. This implies $Ax=ABy=0$ that means $x\in Ker(A)$

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but how did you see that ? Also, why we have $x=By$ ? and why does the matrices have an image and a kernel, aren't they properties of linear transformations ?

Comment: For every $m\times n$ matrix $A$, we can see as linear transformation from$\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}^m$. So we will have kernel and image. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)